# 'jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager' when using Hibernate 5.6

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-migration

I am getting above error while configuring Jakarta Persistence.

I added this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

This is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence 
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    version="3.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence 
        https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd
    "
>
        
    <!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
        
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!--  DB Connection -->
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="Hakim"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="hakim@123"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/learn"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
        <class>com.hakim.entity.BookAuthor</class>
    </persistence-unit>
    
</persistence>
```

This is my entity class

```
package com.hakim.entity;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import jakarta.persistence.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Hakim
 */
@Entity
public class BookAuthor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "FIRST")
    @NotNull
    private String first;

    @Size(max = 30)
    @NotNull()
    @Column(name = "LAST")
    private String last;

    @Size(max=200)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "BIO")
    private String bio;

    public BookAuthor(String first, String last, String bio) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.bio = bio;
    }
    
    

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof BookAuthor)) {
            return false;
        }
        BookAuthor other = (BookAuthor) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BookAuthor{" + "id=" + id + ", first=" + first + ", last=" + last + ", bio=" + bio + '}';
    }

    

}
```

This is main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistence");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            
            
            BookAuthor author=new BookAuthor("Sadiul","Hakim","I am a Full Stack Java Developer.");
            
            
            em.persist(author);
            
            transaction.commit();
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is complete stack trace

```
Jan 21, 2023 3:18:35 PM jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
WARNING: jakarta.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myPersistence
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at com.hakim.entity.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I also tried to add this dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And added this provider

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Stll getting same error

```
Jan 21, 2023 3:18:35 PM jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
WARNING: jakarta.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myPersistence
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at com.hakim.entity.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Please help me how do i start with Jakarta Persistence 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Try using Hibernate 6.x. Hibernate 5.x still uses `javax.persistence`. Note that the groupId changed; see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core

Comment: Thank you. It is working. It was a versioning problem.I have another question. What about this "jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"?If i set 'create' it creates the table everytime. I do not want to create the table everytime. I just want to create the table once when no table exists. What should i use as value? Is it none?

Comment: You can set it to `none`, but then you have to create the table yourself / externally. That's my personal preference, using Liquibase or Flyway to handle the database updates.